# Accessing form input with HTML <a href...>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form that is queried with PHP to search for animals: `animals.php`

Everything works great however I was wondering if I can also access the form with an HTML anchor tag. So when you click:

`<a href="">giraffe</a>`

it will query the DB for a giraffe through `animals.php`.

```
 <form  method="post" action="s.php?go"  id="searchform">
   <input class="search" type="text" name="heyworld">
   <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
 </form>
```

My PHP query works like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_GET['go']) && preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z0-9#@]+/", $_POST['msg'])){
//query the db
//echo the results
```

Comment: would you be able to access it by having the a href="animals.php?go=giraffe">giraffe</a> ??

Comment: no unfortunately i believe it doesn't work like that in this case

Comment: it WOULD work, if you made the PHP script accept all data by GET instead of POST (which would make it simpler than the answer I posted below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***(edit) FIRST OF ALL: Your PHP is unsafe: please take a couple minutes and read about SQL injection: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***

Since you need to POST your data to the script, a simple HREF won't do the job. However, you CAN:

Make another small, invisible form wrapper with an invisible text field with "giraffe" as default value, and make the submit as text

```
<form  method="post" action="s.php?go"  id="searchform">    
    <input class="search" type="hidden" name="heyworld" value="giraffee" />   
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="giraffee" value="Search" />  
</form>
```

Now, for the actual HREF you have 2 options: CSS the button to make it identical to a link, or make it a link, which will submit the (hidden) form with form.submit()

Here's a link explaining this:
[How to HTTP POST from a link without JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747869/how-to-http-post-from-a-link-without-js)

(edit) If you want to do it with GET, you just switch the global you take your data from in the script(note that this is STILL UNSAFE CODE, but I haven't written PHP in a couple years so I better leave the tutoring to someone more qualified), and modify your HTML form to submit data by GET:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['go']) && preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z0-9#@]+/", $_GET['msg']))
```

now your HREF can go to `s.php?go&submit&msg=giraffee` - note that for the way your script is made noe, you need to send submit (empty string is ok, since you only check `isset()` or something like that :)

Comment: edited answer, it was too important to be left in a comment :)

Comment: (don't warry Dragos i did indeed sanitize the php on input and on output, just dummed down the question to make it more fun :D- thanks for the help ! )